# Problem When Creating Custom Class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

With the code below:

---

```
class Int_set(list):
def __init__(self):
    self.vals=[]
    self.index=0
    
def insert(self, elm): #assume a string of numbers
    for x in elm:
        if x not in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(int(x))
    return self.vals
            
def member(self, elm):
    return elm in self.vals 

def remove(self, elm):
    try:
        self.vals.remove(elm)
    except:
        raise ValueError(str(elm)+' not found')
        
def get_members(self):
    return self.vals[:]

def __str__(self):
    if self.vals == []:
        return '[]'
    self.vals.sort()
    result = ''
    for e in self.vals:
        result = result + str(e) + ','
    return f'{{{result[:-1]}}}'
   
def union(self, other):
    '''add all non-duplicate elements from other set to self set'''
    print(len(other))
    for e in range(len(other)):
        if other[e] not in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(other[e])
        else:
            continue
    return self.vals

set1=Int_set()
set1.insert('123456')
print(set1.get_members())

set2=Int_set()
set2.insert('987')
print(set2.get_members())

print(set1.union(set2))
```

---

I get output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[9, 8, 7]
0 # the print(len(other)) in def union
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Notice that the def union(self, other) did not add in all the unique numbers from set2 to set1. However, if I use:

```
print(set1.union(set2.vals))
```

then I get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[9, 8, 7]
3 # the print(len(other)) in def union
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7]
```

What is causing this? I assume set2 inside `.union(set2)` was in the state when it was initialized(thus it's an empty list). But I inserted some numbers inside and printed it out

Comment: why don't you just use a `set` instead of making a class ??!

Comment: You didn't accept any answer. Did none of the answers solve your problem? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `len` on the instance of `Int_set`. This is derived from `list` and gives you the length of the instance itself which is `0`. You need to overwrite `__len__` in your class and give back the value of the instances `val`.

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.vals)
```

And you have to change your `union` method too. At the moment you iterate over the members of the instance of `Int_set` and there are none. You have to iterate over the `vals` attribute.

```
def union(self, other):
    '''add all non-duplicate elements from other set to self set'''
    print(len(other))
    for element in other.vals:
        if element not in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(element)
        else:
            continue
    return self.vals
```

Overall it's unclear why you decided to make `Int_set` a subclass of `list` since you use no features from the `list` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to read values from class itself, you are using `other` instead of `other.vals`. You have answered your question when you tried with

```
print(set1.union(set2.vals))
```

So you can change your function to this:

```
def union(self, other):
        '''add all non-duplicate elements from other set to self set'''
        print(len(other.vals))
        for e in range(len(other.vals)):
            if other.vals[e] not in self.vals:
                self.vals.append(other.vals[e])
            else:
                continue
        return self.vals
```